# GridView elements changes their place dynamically when scroll screen

Tags: android

**i have a gridview layout, and all items are insert very fine,**

now if I check on big screen then all work done is fine, because no scrolling is required

but if I check on small screen then items are changed their position dynamically,

bereif example is given below:-

**like I have 28 items and arranged in a grid view 7*4, now if upto 20 items are shown in first screen, now remaining 8 is shown while i scroll screen down, but now some elements of first or second row is aslo put in last row.**

code is here

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        Context mContext;
        //public static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 10;
        public ImageAdapter(Context c)
        {
            mContext = c;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return providers.length;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View v;
            if(convertView==null)
            {
                LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
                v = li.inflate(R.layout.icontext, null);
                TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
                tv.setText(providers[position]);
                ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
            }
            else
            {
                v = convertView;
            }
            return v;
        }
```

Comment: Can publish any code? For example your adapter code?

Comment: I paste the ImageAdapter code, plz see it

Comment: hey i paste the code, now can you suggest me

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You should change your `getView` method like this.

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.icontext, null);
        }else{
            v = convertView;
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
        tv.setText(providers[position]);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

        return v;
    }
```

Your problem is that when you use `convertView` it stores old data form the first records. Convert view is used to avoid layout inflation from resource which costs you time and memory. You should use the old inflated view, but set new data.

Comment: Hi, I am having same problem. But I have checkBox in place of TextView. When ever there is change in view, the checkboxes which are checked changes

Comment: Its work for me, but while Scrolling its not working smoothly..??

Comment: how to achieve smooth scrolling in this?

Comment: I've update my code but it's not working, any help please I need it badly:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401630/gridview-images-are-changing-postion-when-scrolling

Comment: I also confirm that scrolling get's really laggy after this modification. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I have just deleted the

```
if(convertView==null)
```

it works

Comment: Yea, that fixes the issue. But the performance becomes totally terrible.

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thanks Boris