# GridView with custom ImageAdapter doesn't update after dataset changes

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I'm implementing a gallery of images with support for multiple item selection. The main layout is a `GridView` which uses a custom `Adapter`. Every displayed item is a combination `ImageView` + `CheckBox`. If several checkboxes are checked I want to uncheck them all simply by touching any image in the `GridView`. I'm calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` for implementing this functionality. Unfortunately this "uncheck all" feature doesn't work. I'm still a newbie so probably there is something basic that I don't understand. Could somebody tell me what is wrong with my `Adapter`? Thanks.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // References to our images
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_1, R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_1, R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_1, R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_1, R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3
    };

    // The layout inflater used to retrieve gallery children layouts
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    // Array used to update checkboxes
    public boolean[] checkboxesState = new boolean[getCount()];

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
                c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // Define the initial checked/unchecked state of the checkboxes
        for(int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {
            checkboxesState[i] = false;
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /* Create a new View for each cell displayed in the GridView.
     * In our case a View is an instance of RelativeLayout from which
     * we can extract the image and checkbox to be displayed in the cell
     */
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View cell = convertView;
        if (cell == null) {
            // No View passed, create one.
            cell = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem, null);
            // Setup the View content
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)cell.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) cell.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
            checkBox.setChecked(checkboxesState[position]);
            checkBox.setId(position);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(downsample(mThumbIds[position]));

            // Setup the View behavior
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Uncheck all checked items
                    uncheckAll();
                }
            });

            checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    checkboxesState[cb.getId()] = cb.isChecked();
                }
            });
        }
        return cell;
    }

    private Bitmap downsample(int resId){
        // Some code here
    }

    private void uncheckAll() {
        // This code does not work. GridView is not refreshed
        for(int i = 0; i < checkboxesState.length; i++) {
            checkboxesState[i] = false;
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**Update**

I've realised that my initial post doesn't describe exactly how the uncheckAll method fails. What happens when I have N checked checkboxes and call the uncheckAll method is:

- the initially checked checkboxes are unchecked
- a new group of N checkboxes are checked

This behavior made me to think that maybe the gridview items were, unexpectedly, changing their positions in the `GridView` so I added a `TextView` with a unique name to every item. My thought was correct: when I scrolled the screen the items change their position in the `GridView`. The same happens when uncheckAll is called. I've found a solution working for me [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055730/gridview-elements-changes-their-place-dynamically-when-scroll-screen).

Note: I didn't realise about the moving problem at the very beginning because at this stage of development I was using the same `ImageView` resource for every `GridView` item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is mostly likely that your getView() method correctly initialises a new cell view but never updates the state of a cell view that has been recycled. So essentially each cell view will only ever display the state it was initialised to. It should look something like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View cell = convertView;

    if (cell == null) {
        // No View passed, create one.
        cell = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem, null);
        // Setup the View content
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)cell.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) cell.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
        checkBox.setChecked(checkboxesState[position]);
        checkBox.setId(position);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(downsample(mThumbIds[position]));

        // Setup the View behavior
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Uncheck all checked items
                uncheckAll();
            }
        });

        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                checkboxesState[cb.getId()] = cb.isChecked();
            }
        });
    } else {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)cell.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) cell.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
        checkBox.setChecked(checkboxesState[position]);
        checkBox.setId(position);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(downsample(mThumbIds[position]));
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Additionally to improve the performance of your getView() method take a look at this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It points in the same direction of the thread I mentioned in my post update and works fine.I didn't know the tutorial. I'll try to apply it to my code.

Comment: Four years later I give you an upvote, right? Well what can I say? This one was making me crazy! Thanks!